# How does someone terminate a (remote) headless Java application?

Tags: java, headless

I'm new to headless applications and, as the title describes, I want to know what methods are there to terminate a headless application? While on the topic, how does one normally deploy the application?

Thank you!

Comment: Just kill the JVM? Or is that a webapp container like tomcat and you want to terminate this application only?

Comment: Do you like `kill {pid}` ?

Comment: thank you for replying, fge. A little of both because this application can be used in 2 contexts: a webapp and the more traditional desktop app. It's been a long time since I programmed client-server so I don't know the methods of how one kills the JVM remotely etc.

Comment: edited: thank you peter. thinking about it, regardless of where it is deployed, any method to kill the process would suffice, I assume? With that in mind, is this then the best way to handle/administrate the application?

Comment: killing jvm is not a good practice. what happen any open connections if you use db ? is it  an web application or standalone ? if standalone, running in a port ?

Comment: I fully understand that. I'm the first to admit not having full knowledge regarding this topic so I was fielding for best practices, and even worst practices that work. But thank you for pointing out the valid points, I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basic solution principle:** On the server side (the headless app, I call it the service) have a ServerSocket open that listens to a certain port. From the outside, connect to that ServerSocket and send a certain message. When the server application gets the connection request, it can act upont it.

**Hints:**
However, be certain that you use something like a secret message or some other authentication method like signatures and SSL, because else everyone who knows the servers port could close your application.

BTW This same solution principle can also be used to pass new parameters to an already running application, like a double-click on some audio file in you browser will play the new title in the current audio player and not in a new instance. (the new instance actually gets started but sends the new file/title to the older instance, which catches it and switches to that new song)

**Additional:** When you have another way of sending data to the app, as in web pages where you can POST/GET data, you can also parse that input for a specific message.

Comment: Ah. Thank you Jay. I did think to put in a kill-switch within the program itself but I also wanted to know if there were other, perhaps more expedient, methods to kill a session. once the application is deployed, little or no support for it would be provided afterwards, so I was hoping to provide information to users on how to start->terminate the application, being as meticulous as possible. Anyway, since it's already in a mature state with regard to its client and server implementations, this will be the primary method recommended to users. Thanks again for making the choice clear :)

Comment: Two good and easy approaches are basic telnet support (simple text messaging, for all applications) or restricted pages (check cookie/sessions etc, used for web apps).
However be careful with external kills like 'kill {pid}' because that might leave chopped files, broken communications and even blocked ports (e.g. problem with windows sockets).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) which starts new OS process

Example:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
...
p.destroy();
```